# Localhost Angular apps 404 when using Firefox browser. Works fine in Edge and Chrome

Tags: angular, typescript, firefox, pycharm

When working on an angular project and struggling to get the debugger to work for Pycharm, somewhere along the line Firefox stopped working with all angular project and returns 404 every time. I created a fresh angular app to make sure and it works on Edge and Chrome, but not Firefox. ALL PROJECTS BEING RUN ON LOCALHOST:4200

Attempts:
Cleared cookies and cache, updated Firefox, new angular app with no changes. Both my large project and the new app worked fine in other browsers but would give me a 404 screen in Firefox.

Theory:
I do not believe this is a code issue but a settings issue somewhere in firefox or my windows pc.

Additional attempts to solve based on comments:
both https and http still result in 404 only on firefox browser.

Comment: open `http://localhost:4200`, not `https://localhost:4200`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.